# How to get all rows by joining 2 dataframes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have 2 dataframes:

```
Location    Places  Date        Date_part   Sector      Category    units   
USA         Place_1 7/1/2021    7/1/2021    Cars        Passenger   200
IND         Place_2 7/1/2021    7/1/2021    Cars        Passenger   180     
COL         Place_3 7/1/2021    7/1/2021    Trucks      Goods       100
```

```
Location    Places      Clicks        
USA         Place_1     320       
COL         Place_3     730       
CAN         Place_4     84
```

I need to create a new dataframes like this

```
Location    Places  Date        Date_part   Sector      Category    units   ClicksPerDay   
USA         Place_1 7/1/2021    7/1/2021    Cars        Passenger   200     320
IND         Place_2 7/1/2021    7/1/2021    Cars        Passenger   180     
COL         Place_3 7/1/2021    7/1/2021    Trucks      Goods       100     730
CAN         Place_4 7/1/2021    7/1/2021    Cars        Passenger           84
```

I need ClicksPerDay column to be created from Clicks and value to be available where ever Sector= Cars and Category=Passenger

I tried using
`df_result = df1.unionByName(df2)`

But I need to achieve this by joining 2 dataframes. The result dataframe should be having all rows from both dataframes
Please share any other approaches.

Comment: What you need is `join`, not `union`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Joining 2 Dataframes on multiple columns Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47908827/joining-2-dataframes-on-multiple-columns-pandas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to join the Dataframes by 'location' you can preform `df1.join(df2, 'Location', how='outer')`

This will give the output you specified. You can read more [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join.html)
In regards to the column ClicksPerDay, you can do that with `withColumn`. As far as I see, all that's different is the name of the column so you can do:

```
 import pyspark.sql.functions as F
 df.withColumn("ClicksPerDay",F.col("Clicks")).drop("Clicks").
```

If the joined table matches the original table where Sector=Cars and Category=Passenger
Then no further action is required, if not then you can set specific rows to null according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57435380/pyspark-fillna-specific-rows-based-on-condition) answer

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with an Outer [Join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join.html).

And replace the neccessary/desired columns within `sparkDF1` are `Null` you can replace them with the values from `sparkDF2`

## Data Preparation

```
input_str1 = """
Location    Places  Date        Date_part   Sector      Category    units   
USA         Place_1 7/1/2021    7/1/2021    Cars        Passenger   200
IND         Place_2 7/1/2021    7/1/2021    Cars        Passenger   180     
COL         Place_3 7/1/2021    7/1/2021    Trucks      Goods       100
""".split()

input_value1 = list(map(lambda x:x.strip(),input_str1))

cols1 = input_value1[:7]

n = len(input_value1[7:])

input_list1 = [tuple(input_value1[i:i+7]) for i in range(7,n+1,7)]


input_str2 = """
Location    Places      Clicks        
USA         Place_1     320       
COL         Place_3     730       
CAN         Place_4     84 
""".split()

input_value2 = list(map(lambda x:x.strip(),input_str2))

cols2 = input_value2[:3]

n = len(input_value2[3:])

input_list2 = [tuple(input_value2[i:i+3]) for i in range(3,n+1,3)]


sparkDF1 = sql.createDataFrame(input_list1,cols1)
sparkDF2 = sql.createDataFrame(input_list2,cols2)

sparkDF1.show()

+--------+-------+--------+---------+------+---------+-----+
|Location| Places|    Date|Date_part|Sector| Category|units|
+--------+-------+--------+---------+------+---------+-----+
|     USA|Place_1|7/1/2021| 7/1/2021|  Cars|Passenger|  200|
|     IND|Place_2|7/1/2021| 7/1/2021|  Cars|Passenger|  180|
|     COL|Place_3|7/1/2021| 7/1/2021|Trucks|    Goods|  100|
+--------+-------+--------+---------+------+---------+-----+

sparkDF2.show()

+--------+-------+------+
|Location| Places|Clicks|
+--------+-------+------+
|     USA|Place_1|   320|
|     COL|Place_3|   730|
|     CAN|Place_4|    84|
+--------+-------+------+
```

**Note - All columns are Strings**

## Join

```
finalDF = sparkDF1.join(sparkDF2
                    ,(sparkDF1['Location'] == sparkDF2['Location'])
                    & (sparkDF1['Places'] == sparkDF2['Places'])
                    ,'outer'
                ).select(sparkDF1["*"]
                        ,sparkDF2['Clicks'].alias('ClicksPerDay')
                        ,sparkDF2['Location'].alias('Location_Secondary')
                        ,sparkDF2['Places'].alias('Places_Secondary')
                    )
finalDF.show()
+--------+-------+--------+---------+------+---------+-----+------------+------------------+----------------+
|Location| Places|    Date|Date_part|Sector| Category|units|ClicksPerDay|Location_Secondary|Places_Secondary|
+--------+-------+--------+---------+------+---------+-----+------------+------------------+----------------+
|    null|   null|    null|     null|  null|     null| null|          84|               CAN|         Place_4|
|     IND|Place_2|7/1/2021| 7/1/2021|  Cars|Passenger|  180|        null|              null|            null|
|     USA|Place_1|7/1/2021| 7/1/2021|  Cars|Passenger|  200|         320|               USA|         Place_1|
|     COL|Place_3|7/1/2021| 7/1/2021|Trucks|    Goods|  100|         730|               COL|         Place_3|
+--------+-------+--------+---------+------+---------+-----+------------+------------------+----------------+
```

## Replacing Null Values

Precedence is given to `sparkDF1` , which you can modify as your your requirement

```
finalDF = finalDF.withColumn('Location',F.when(F.col('Location').isNull()
                            ,F.col('Location_Secondary')).otherwise(F.col('Location')))\
                .withColumn('Places',F.when(F.col('Places').isNull()
                            ,F.col('Places_Secondary')).otherwise(F.col('Places')))\


final_column_list = ['Location','Places','Date','Date_part','Sector','Category','units','ClicksPerDay']

finalDF = finalDF.select(*final_column_list).orderBy(F.col('Location').desc())

finalDF.show()

+--------+-------+--------+---------+------+---------+-----+------------+
|Location| Places|    Date|Date_part|Sector| Category|units|ClicksPerDay|
+--------+-------+--------+---------+------+---------+-----+------------+
|     USA|Place_1|7/1/2021| 7/1/2021|  Cars|Passenger|  200|         320|
|     IND|Place_2|7/1/2021| 7/1/2021|  Cars|Passenger|  180|        null|
|     COL|Place_3|7/1/2021| 7/1/2021|Trucks|    Goods|  100|         730|
|     CAN|Place_4|    null|     null|  null|     null| null|          84|
+--------+-------+--------+---------+------+---------+-----+------------+
```